# How to render a block in Blockly?

Tags: javascript, blockly

I went through the `Workspace` documentation and have attempted to use the `newBlock` method like so:

`var block = workspace.newBlock("string_length")` to add a custom block which is defined like this:

```
Blockly.Blocks['string_length'] = {
  init: function() {
    this.jsonInit({
      "message0": 'length of %1',
      "args0": [
        {
          "type": "input_value",
          "name": "VALUE",
          "check": "String"
        }
      ],
      "output": "Number",
      "colour": 160,
      "tooltip": "Returns number of letters in the provided text.",
      "helpUrl": "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp"
    });
  }
};
```

Blockly tends to throw an exception when a block prototype name is not recognized but it seems to recognize it and assign its unique id and other information.

The block turned out not to be visible even after attempting to add it to topblocks.

Comment: Why did you post an question just to answer it immediately after?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When manually adding blocks there is a certain process you have to go through.

Make sure the block was added correctly, meaning `block = workspace.newBlock("your_type")` doesn't throw an error and block is initialized.

Next you have to call the `block.initSvg()` function, the documentation says that you have to call either the `initSvg()` or `initModel()` function:

> Call initModel on all fields on the block. May be called more than
>   once. Either initModel or initSvg must be called after creating a
>   block and before the first interaction with it. Interactions include
>   UI actions (e.g. clicking and dragging) and firing events (e.g.
>   create, delete, and change).

But the `initModel()` function seems to give me the same error as when I had not initialized it yet, the documentation as far as I can see does not give a clear distinction between the two either.

After calling the `initSvg()` function you should be able to render the wanted block by calling `.render()` on your **workspace** object.

sources:

[Block documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Block)

[Workspace documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace)